# Replace is replacing 182 entries instead of just 1?

Tags: mysql

I have one entry in my database with the ‘package_id’ 1

When I execute the following command I get the response:

> 182 rows affected

```
update bookings set package_id = replace(package_id, '1', '109')
```

I then find any “package_id” that contains a 1 has been replaced with 109?

That’s not what I wanted :-(

Comment: [Please read about how MySQL `Replace` actually works](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Answer (score 2):

Your statement is incorrect. You should read what replace does.

> MySQL REPLACE() replaces all the occurrences of a substring within a string.

If you just want to change the package_id from 1 to 109 you should:

```
update bookings set package_id = '109' where package_id = '1'
```

- If your package_id is a number you should not use the single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Nick, you are misusing the replace function. Replace function will replace all occurences of 1 by 109 in field package_id.

I think a where clause is missing.